# Chrome sponsored tag logo is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, sponsored-tags

[google-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) is a sponsored tag. This has the usual five links and lo.. the logo is broken. It links to

> http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-logo-google-chrome.png

which returns 404.

Comment: Well, at least it broke gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! Looks like there was a purging of old image files. This also affected [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) earlier this week (that one is also fixed).

Thank you for the heads up!